# Yellow-highlighted chat messages are shortened

Tags: bug, chat, design

When somebody replies to or pings me, and I click on the little notification circle, their message is highlighted in yellow. It also makes the right side of the `.message` div shorter by about 50 pixels.

The problem with that is that the flag, star, and reply buttons are contained within the `.message`, so they are moved ~50px to the left from where I expect them to be. Of course by the time I figure out where they've moved to, the message becomes un-highlighted and they move back to where they normally are.

This bug is most likely caused by this snippet that's in [the main chat.meta.SE CSS file](http://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/css/chat.meta.stackexchange.com.css?v=78b92d0da19a):

```
.message.highlight {
    margin-right: 48px
}
```

Is this supposed to be that way? Is there even any point to the `.message.highlight` section? Should it be removed?

Comment: Just curious, did you purposely do anything weird with the title of this question? I'm seeing a whole bunch of `&#8203;`'s at the start of it in Chrome's inspector, is that intentional?

Comment: @odnU Oh, lol. That. No, it was not intentional. It was left over from a bug I was testing, but didn't post the question for.

Comment: @odnU Ha. Beat you by two seconds.