# Duplicate edits submitted at nearly the same time both go through

Tags: bug, edits, revisions-list

I posted [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272222/238586) a short while ago and accidentally left a few zero-width spaces from a bug I was testing earlier. odnU pointed out my error, and we both made edits to fix it, which you can see in [the revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/272222/revisions) (edits #2 and #3). We both made the exact same edit (removing the 10-20 spaces), and submitted the edit within 2 seconds of each other. The odd thing is that the second edit created a new revision in the history, even though it changed nothing from the revision before it.

I have no idea how this is possible, but I'm pretty sure it's not supposed to be.

Comment: Don't think it's a bug, and pretty sure it's already reported anyway - will try to find.

Comment: @ShadowWizard How do you find these duplicates!? I spent so much time making sure this wasn't a dupe, and then you come along... :P

Comment: Way too much time spent on MSE... ;) (anyhow, I'll reveal the secret just this time... http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bedits%5D+empty+is%3Aquestion)